# Overleaf ignores errors, how to avoid it?

Tags: overleaf, compilation-error

I would like to know if there is any way to prevent Overleaf from ignoring the errors that do appear when compiling on the desktop.

For example, the following template code runs perfectly on Overleaf, but in TeXMaker (I'm using MikTeX), there are errors related to the `declaretheorem` code lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,mathtools}

\usepackage{thmtools}
%Entornos matemáticos en español

\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=0pt, spacebelow=0pt,
    headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
    notefont=\bfseries, notebraces={(}{)},
    bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
    postheadspace=1em,
    qed={},
    numberwithin=section,
]{Theorem}

\declaretheorem[style=Theorem, name=Theorem]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=Theorem, name=Lemma, numberlike=theorem]{lemma}
\declaretheorem[style=Theorem, name=Corollary, numberlike=theorem]{corollary}
\declaretheorem[style=Theorem, name=Proposition, numberlike=theorem]{proposition}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Your abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

Your introduction goes here! Simply start writing your document and use the Recompile button to view the updated PDF preview. Examples of commonly used commands and features are listed below, to help you get started.

Once you're familiar with the editor, you can find various project settings in the Overleaf menu, accessed via the button in the very top left of the editor. To view tutorials, user guides, and further documentation, please visit our \href{https://www.overleaf.com/learn}{help library}, or head to our plans page to \href{https://www.overleaf.com/user/subscription/plans}{choose your plan}.

\section{Some examples to get started}

\begin{theorem}\label{th:example}
    No three positive integers $a, b$, and c satisfy the equation $a^n + b^n = c^n$ for any integer value of $n$ greater than 2.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proposition}
    Hi! I'm a proposition.
\end{proposition}
As explained in theorem \ref{th:example}...

\end{document}
```

I would like Overleaf to also display these errors correctly and not force the compilation because

1. sometimes I need to compile a document online and then on the desktop when I don't have internet,
2. when submitting the article to a journal, the code must run well on the desktop.

I appreciate any ideas you may have.

Comment: Your code compiles without error on my MacBook Air, which runs MacOS 13.5 "Ventura" and MacTeX2023 (with all updates applied). When did you last update your MixTeX distribution?

Comment: The main reason Overleaf doesn’t display any error (at least in my case) is, well, there are no errors. Please, edit your question to add the errors with MikTeX/TeXMaker.

Comment: overleaf does not ignore errors it always adds a red flash with an error count at the top of the view

Comment: please edit the question to have an error, and show the exact error message from the log file generated by miktex

Comment: You may have different versions of some files than are being used by Overleaf.  Version numbers are recorded in the log file.  Compare the two log files and look for differences.  That may be the source of the different behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for this option?

[image]

But, at first glance, your code has no error, so probably you have a *local* broken installation... Or something you're not showing here. Please, add the error you have in your local run.

Comment: It keeps ignoring them :(

Comment: @DanielCheca it never ignores errors, it uses a standard texlive tex installation. The example in your question has no error